# Email Author Sharepoint

Tags: document, retention

I have created a new column in my files and library view, named 'Author', as a person or group column. I have made this column mandatory to people to fill out, so that a name gets associated with this document. I want to have my retention policy start a workflow to email this 'Author' that is associated with the document. How is this possible?

I was creating a new workflow and couldn't find how to email the user I made people associated with the documents

[image]

Comment: You need to change Return Field as 'AS String' to 'Email Address'

Comment: It is still asking me to return a field in the 'find the list item' and  value??

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place.  It should be current item not documents

Answer (score 2):

I hope your Author is coming from the current item.

You can follow below steps

1. Change "Data Source" to "Current Item"
2. Field From Source - Author
3. Return field as "Email Address"

Comment: Just a point to note in addition to the answer, the "Author" is the default internal name of column "Created By" in SharePoint. In case you get any issue that email are going to the Creator than the custom Author, you may be need to change the internal name of your column.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanTahir What?!? Changing the `InternalName`? No way! However, if you create a column where the internal name is already given, the system adds a counter. In his case I'm sure the created internal name for `Author` is `Author0`